# How to change arrow of multiple accordion?

Tags: jquery, css

I've created multiple `accordions` in jQuery UI, but I have a problem:

How do I change the arrow icons if my accordions are nested like this?

[image]

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BMJAv/1/)**

Comment: It is working Fine. What is the issue?

Comment: issue is that i want to change arrow all three level how to change can u tell me please .. and now arrow is the defrent all three level accrodian

Comment: You mean, close the panels of the child accordions until they are clicked to open and not like what is happening the way it is now. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
var icons1 = {
  header: "ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e",
  activeHeader: "ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s"
};

var icons2 = {
  header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
  activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
};

var icons3 = {
  header: ".ui-icon-arrow-1-e",
  activeHeader: ".ui-icon-arrow-1-s"
};    

$( ".accoraccordionBorder" ).accordion({
    header: "h1" ,
    heightStyle: "content",
    icons: icons1
});


$( ".accoraccordionBorder2" ).accordion({
    header: "h2" ,
    heightStyle: "content",
    icons: icons2
});

$( ".accoraccordionBorder3" ).accordion({
    header: "h3" ,
    heightStyle: "content",
    icons: icons3
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mastermindw/BMJAv/3/

for customized arrows as shown in picture you need to edit the picture given by default in

```
jquery-ui.css, line 281 
.ui-state-active .ui-icon { background-image: url(images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png)/*{iconsActive}*/; }
```

Comment: its already there in jsfiddle, kindly check the link.
http://jsfiddle.net/mastermindw/BMJAv/2/

Comment: i check to this all image is same but i want to different images in my accordion ... as like this my Images check to my Question and see my example images..

Comment: updated jsfiddle, please check.
for customized arrows you need to edit this picture 

given by default in jquery-ui.css, line 281

.ui-state-active .ui-icon {
background-image: url(images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png)/*{iconsActive}*/;
}

Answer (score 0):

Just set another background image in place of the arrow

The current style is (`jquery-ui.css, row 281`)

```
.ui-state-active .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png");
}
...
.ui-icon-triangle-1-s {
    background-position: -64px -16px;
}
```

so you just need to create another rule with at least the same specificity (or using `!important`) with another background image and position